# Geometry Nodes Terrain LOD system. Stiching holes on LOD borders

Tags: edges, geometry-nodes, procedural

Currently I'm trying to develop an LOD (Level of detail) system for a terrain mesh based on geometry nodes.
I use a Separate Geometry node to split a grid into circular LOD regions and subdivide the inner regions further. This arises the problem of creating holes in the border zones of the mesh where the LODs change.

[image]
[image]

Here is my node setup:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Can any of you think of a solution to fix this problem?

Here is my final solution thanks to André Zmuda:

[image]

[image]

Many thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For the sake of simplicity, I used a raycast setup to generate this example. But the concept should be transferable to your setup.

[image: result]

[image: node setup]

[image]

By separating the geometry, you double your edges and this creates the holes. The core of my solution are the following nodes:

[image: core nodes]

After separating the geometry, I choose the border of the subdivided mesh and place all vertices of this border onto the nearest point of the rest of the mesh. This closes the holes. Afterwards I merge by distance to weld everything together.